# Websphere Developer Tools for traditional 8.5 on macOS - Unable to connect to WAS running on Docker

Tags: eclipse, docker, websphere, ibm-rad

I'm trying to figure out how to develop for Websphere 8.5 (traditional) App Server on a Mac using Eclipse w/Websphere plugin and Docker to run Websphere.

I have a Macbook Pro and since Websphere (traditional) Application Server isn't available for Macs, I have it running as a Docker container on my machine. As part of the Docker setup, I forward all of the relevant ports (9080, 9443, etc.) so for all practical purposes it appears like it's running on localhost (e.g. http://localhost:9080).

The problem is that the Websphere Eclipse plugin's setup wizard will not permit you to add a server running on localhost as "WAS on OS X isn't supported" (even though in this case it's running in a Linux docker container). What I've been trying to do is trick the plugin into treating the docker'd WAS as a remote connection but haven't been successful.

This seems like it would be a pretty common use case since WAS isn't supported on Macs. Anyone run into this?

Comment: I've come across a couple pieces of this puzzle so, while this isn't a complete answer, you may find this https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional/issues/168#issuecomment-535947357  piece helpful if you're still stuck.     As you noted, the plugin logic won't let you use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as a remote connection, you need another IP address).  Maybe that helps a bit..

Comment: There is already a tag, [ibm-rad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-rad) which should be used in lieu of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rational-application-developer).